# Sorting MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have some relative simple questions about how it works MySQL with PHP. For beginning I have created "products" table. The table is this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| name                          | brand   | type      | color | price |
|-------------------------------+---------+-----------+----------------
| Samsung S5230 (white          | samsung | s5230     | white |    80 |
| Samsung S5230 (black)         | samsung | s5230     | black |    95 |
| Samsung Wave 723 (black)      | samsung | wave723   | black |   200 |
| Apple iPhone 4G 16GB (white)  | apple   | iphone4g  | white |   500 |
| Apple iPhone 4G 32GB (white)  | apple   | iphone4g  | white |   600 |
| Apple iPhone 4G 16GB (black)  | apple   | iphone4g  | black |   450 |
| Apple iPhone 4G 32GB (black)  | apple   | iphone4g  | black |   550 |
| Apple iPhone 3GS 16GB (white) | apple   | iphone3gs | white |   300 |
| Apple iPhone 3GS 8GB (black)  | apple   | iphone3gs | black |   200 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to create a PHP script who sorts my products. I want to sort combinations in the picture below:
[image]

The first image is the default state. 
The second image is when the Samsung checkbox is checked.
The third image is when the Apple checkbox is checked.
Sort by price menu has 3 options: Random, Ascending, Descending.
PRODUCT LIST HERE is the location where i want to make the MySQL selection.
Thank you for your time, regards.

Comment: Ok. Now we know what you want to do. But what do you want?

Comment: I want to create a PHP script who sorts my products. This is what I want. What you see in the image is a html printscreen with no functions that doesn't works. I want to create a functional PHP script.

Comment: What should happen if both the Apple and the Samsung checkboxes are checked?

Comment: http://postimage.org/image/s91cpzyit/ is not working

Comment: @Sara It works for me, but try here instead http://i.stack.imgur.com/GZpSF.png

Comment: it both apple and samsung checkboxes are cheked it will be displayed both products.

Answer (score 1):

Well, considering that you want to so many options to sort, I would advise against writing a billion SQL Queries to get the correct order, as it is in no-awy scalable or efficent, not to talk about - a design flaw.

I would instead get the entire result set, and sort it using javascript, there is a great jQuery plugin for that, called [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)

Comment: You think sorting the entire result set in js is more efficient and more scalable than writing a query that returns the desired records? It may well be more efficient if the dataset is small but it is not more scalable.

Comment: @nnichols I was speaking in context, ofcourse for a large company with a query which pulls a billion records per day I won't advise to do that. put for a dataset of 50-100 records, tablesorter handles that beautifully.

Comment: Thank you very much for advice, but I don't want to create a table. I want to create a PHP script who sort my product with links: for example if i want to display from MySQL table all Apple (brand) iPhone 4G (type) with this link:
products.php?brand=apple&type=iphone4g

Comment: I want to create sorting combinations between brand, type, name, and price.

Comment: Filtering, not sorting. So what have you tried? There are many articles out there on getting started with PHP and MySQL. This is a Q&A site, not a we'll write it for you for free site. How many products will be in your table?

Answer (score 0):

Well, to solve this kind of problems (Where not all products have the same filtering (which is by the way, different than sorting) fields), I use a many to many relationship table, for instance:

```
FieldsToBrands
-------------------
brand_id | field_id
-------------------
1          1
1          2
2          2

Brands
---------------------
brand_id | brand_name
---------------------
1          Apple
2          Samsung

Fields
---------------------
field_id | field_name
---------------------
1          Color
2          Space
```

Which then means that Apple has both Color and Space, and Samsung only has Space. This is called a many-to-many relationship between tables.

Comment: And how cand i do this with PHP? What Space means?

Comment: Space is an example field (4GB, 8GB, 16GB, etc)

Comment: Thank you very much. I had a confusion between sorting and filtering. What I looked for was filtering. This code helped me so much to do what I wanted to do: [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=216525